# Pyplot polar scatter plot color for sign

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib, scatter

I have a pyplot polar scatter plot with signed values.  Pyplot does the "right" thing and creates only a positive axis, then reflects negative values to look as if they are a positive value 180 degrees away.

But, by default, pyplot plots all points using the same color.  So positive and negative values are indistinguishable.

I'd like to easily tell positive values at angle x from negative values at angle (x +/- 180), with positive values red and negative values blue.

I've made no progress creating what should be a very simple color map for this situation.

Help?

Comment: On a side note, newer versions of matplotlib no longer do the "right" thing and "reflect" the negative `r` values. I'm not sure if this is by design or accident.

Comment: I just updated to 2.7.5 and matplotlib 1.2.0, and it still works fine for my particular case.

Comment: Aaaaaaand it's not working in 1.2.1. Sigh.  Back to 1.2.0.

Comment: Please add any details you can (like a MWE) to https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2133

Comment: Since the solution is to split the data in two and plot twice, it is a trivial change to flip the sign and angle, then plot using the desired color for negative values (which works for 1.2.1 and prior versions).  Trivial, but it should not be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the "proper" way to do this, but you could programmatically split your data into two subsets: one containing the positive values and the second containing the negative values.  Then you can call the plot function twice, specifying the color you want for each subset.

It's not an elegant solution, but a solution nonetheless.

Comment: I was hoping for a more elegant solution, but brute force works!

Comment: Agreed. I would love to hear from some matplotlib gurus as to the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: look into listed color maps.

Comment: I would, if "listed color maps" googled to anything relevant.  An example or reference, please?